# Multiple Forms, Multiple Threads, One Process

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

HI everyone,

I'd be interested to know what people think about the concept of an executable that is responsible for starting three individual forms on their own threads. The primary reasons for this approach are to make sure that the forms can't run individually and so that we could pass information between the forms without using IPC.

I'm a bit unsure about the ideal places to create the forms in respect of their threads.  I'm assuming that it would be better to create and show the forms in their own thread. Having said that I'm unsure if this works correctly.  I tried it but Invoking a cross thread call on the forms own thread doesn't work (i.e. the BeginInvoke call doesn't make it back to the ShowWindow method on the other thread)...

```
    private void ShowWindow(string serialNumber)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(delegate() { ShowWindow(serialNumber); }));
        }
        else
        {
            this.Visible = true;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            if (serialNumber != string.Empty)
            {
                knavManagement.SelectedPage = knpActivate;
                activatePage.SerialNumber = serialNumber;
            }
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }
```

I have tried many different ways to invoke the method on its own thread but none of them work, which leads me to think it may be something to do with the underlying threading system, hence my question.

Thankyou!

Chris.

Comment: I'd use all forms from the same thread and not one thread each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments so far guys.

One approach I have found that appears to work is to use Application.Run on each form, which I believe starts the form on its own UI thread.  I'm not too sure of the implications of this, I will report back...

```
    public void StartManagementConsole()
    {            
        ThreadStart start = delegate
        {
            _managementConsole = new ManagementConsole();
            Application.Run(_managementConsole);
        };

        consoleThread = new Thread(start);
        consoleThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        consoleThread.Start();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Windows Forms must all be in created by main UI thread. You could have each form spawn a worker thread to perform the work that needs to be done. The worker threads can communicate with each other without IPC, although you're now in the position where you have to synchronize that inter-thread communication.